# What are the best practices for implementing “My Domain” within the construct of a Trialforce organization?

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, trialforce

As of Winter '16 the “My Domain” feature is now mandatory. Si I'm looking to understand what are the best practices for implementing “My Domain” within the construct of a Trialforce organization?

How does it impact a Managed Package distributed within a Trialforce, and that Managed Package contains Lightning Components in it? Will that block usage of the entire app anyhow? Like if users will be blocked to use our app until My Domains is activated by customer taking a trial?

Comment: Is your app based only on having Lightning components or does it have Visualforce alternatives; as in being what they call "Lightning Ready"?

Comment: Yes the app has Visualforce components and there are plans to make Lightning Components to be included into the app as well. I'm concerned if that will effect our existing VF app in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether your managed package has Lightning Components in it or not, if My Domain isn't enabled, the Visualforce you currently have will display.

If your package doesn't have any Lightning Components in it and My Domain gets enabled *along with* Lightning, your Visualforce will display normally as expected. Salesforce will automatically open a new tab to display your Visualforce unless they're embedded in a Lightning Page in which case a new tab won't be opened. Instead, your Visualforce would need to be wrapped inside the appropriate code.

If the latter applies, see the [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) for more on using VisualForce within Lightning pages. I'd also recommend you visit the Partner Community Lightning Readiness Forum as well as their Lightning and Component Forum if you haven't already been there.

I'll add that be default, My Domain isn't enabled in a Trialforce Org. That's something a customer would need to enable themselves during set-up.

**Edit**

I suggest you go through the [Trailhead Lightning Components module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components). I think it will become clear that your components will need to be namespaced with your domain in order for you and others to use them. It's what distinguishes your Lightning components from other components and how they're referenced. All orgs will need to enable My Domain to use the Lightning Experience.

There's also a new module I suggest you go through titled [Lightning Experience Development](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lex_dev_overview) that may help answer some of your additional questions. It includes a section titled "ISVs, Packaging, and AppExchange". I suggest you try to remember that Lightning isn't yet a fully developed platform and that what's published today could change tomorrow. Salesforce itself admits it's something of a beta that's in progress. There's much that's still to come as Salesforce continues to fill in gaps in the Lightning platform that haven't yet been addressed.

Comment: I've one more query on the same topic, how will it impact the Main Package Dev org? I mean, I've not enabled My Domain in my main Package Dev source org, as I was worried if it will impose any unwanted dependencies when someone installing my package? Considering if I enable My Domain in my package Dev Org, and build a new version (with or without the Lightning Components/Tab), will the Package Throw a Dependency Error on installation that My Domain Need to be enable in order to install my package?

Comment: See my edit. Your users will need to enable My Domain to use Lightning components, but should be able to install since you'll have the visualforce for pages to make it usable if they don't have Lightning enabled. Again, I highly recommend you visit the Partner Community where these issues are addressed and discussed in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev - I tested it out as well, also looked on this on partner community. My tests suggests that the package continued to work as it is, and after installing new version with Lightning Components did not had any adverse effects on usage of VF components. But on opening Lightning Component Tab we get a warning/error that My Domains is not configured so it cannot load the tab.

Comment: That's the behavior I'd expect with the lightning component version. Thanks for confirming it.

Comment: I've one more query on this. What happens if I enable "My Domains" in "Trialforce" Org - How will it impact the new Trials generated from the Trialforce Template? I'm unable to find documentation that guides this query ...

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to be able to enable "My Domain" in a Trialforce Org. That's something which only can be configured when by the user when they set-up and choose their "My Domain". You'd also want to caution them against using a Domain they may want to use later since Salesforce registers it with ICANN at the time it's configured. Although I've not read anything that says they don't, clearly Salesforce will need to enable the capability to enable MyDomain for Trialforce Orgs to help sell the lightning Experience. At the same time, I see no way for them to preconfigure it in advance.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. The trouble with this setup I'm having is, that all Lightning Component Tabs are Hidden in Profiles, if My Domains is not setup. Thus each customer needs to go through with all profiles and Unhide the Tabs manually.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I think it's an appropriate issue to raise in the Partner Community, perhaps in one of the Office Hours sessions if you don't get an answer in one of the Technical Support Groups.